# Trying to run multiple kue jobs at different times, but they're starting at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, scheduled-tasks, kue

I'm trying to run two different jobs on different schedules (see code ex below).  For some reason, the job that is supposed to run once a day at 11pm runs every time the other job runs.  How do I get them to run when I expect them to run? Thank you for your help.

```
const kue = require('kue-scheduler');
const Queue = kue.createQueue();
const jobOneSchedule = '0 0 23 * * *';
const jobTwoSchedule = '0 0 0/1 * * *';

let job1 = Queue.createJob('doJobOne')
                .priority('low')
                .unique('unique_one')
                .removeOnComplete('true');


let job2 = Queue.createJob('doJobTwo')
                .priority('high')
                .unique('unique_two')
                .removeOnComplete('true');


Queue.every(jobOneSchedule, job1);
Queue.every(jobTwoSchedule, job2);


Queue.process('doJobOne', function(job, done){
    console.log('Job one done');
    done();
});

Queue.process('doJobTwo', function(job, done){
    console.log('Job two through');
    done();
});
```

### Workaround

As a workaround, I had to remove all of the job2 stuff and run it like this:

```
// Do job2 stuff every hour (3.6e6 ms)
const jobTwoInterval = 3.6e6;
setInterval(function(){
    console.log('Job two through');
}, jobTwoInterval);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working fine at my end

```
  const jobOneSchedule = '39 11 * * *';   //Runs at 11:39 pm
  const jobTwoSchedule = '*/20 * * * * *';  //Run every twenty seconds
```

Could you try flushing redis and try again.

setInterval has disadvantage that if server restart your job will be never be executed as interval will be cleared.